# JDO datanucleus - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with Jersey/Google App Engine/Maven

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, jersey, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to set up a simple RESTful API with Jersey running on GAE with JDO access to Google's datastore (also using Maven). After I added JDO support to the datastore, when I hit the API I am now getting this error at runtime w/ details below. My hunch tells me its some versioning issues with the JDO dependencies, but I can't seem to figure it out.

**TestJerseyService.java**

```java
@Path("/service")
public class TestJerseyService {

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person testMethod() {
        PersonDaoImp dao = new PersonDaoImp();
        return dao.addPerson();
    }
}
```

**PersonDaoImp.java**

```java
public class PersonDaoImp{

public Person addPerson(){
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName("TestName");

    try {
        pm.makePersistent(e);

    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return p;
}
```

**PMF.java**

```java
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public final class PMF {
    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance =
        JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PMF() {}

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```java
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Key;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;


@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.IDENTITY)
public class Person {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    public Person(){
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**jdoconfig.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">

    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/>
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

**pom.xml snippets**

```xml
<dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
         <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
         <version>1.8.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
         <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
         <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
         <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.11</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
         <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.7</version>
      </dependency>

      <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-release</version>
            <configuration>
               <api>JDO</api>
               <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
               <!-- <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration> -->
               <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>process-classes</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>enhance</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
```

**When I hit the */service/test endpoint I get this error:**

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /exercises/test. Reason:

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getExecutionContext(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/datanucleus/ExecutionContext;

Caused by:

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getExecutionContext(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/datanucleus/ExecutionContext;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:212)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:982)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:359)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getExecutionContext(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/datanucleus/ExecutionContext;
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.<init>(JDOPersistenceManager.java:148)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.newPM(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:845)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:821)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:802)
    at test.dao.PersonDaoImp.addPerson(PersonDaoImp.java:17)
    at test.service.TestJerseyService.testMethod(TestJerseyWS.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:353)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:343)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:237)
    ... 47 more

Caused by:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getExecutionContext(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/datanucleus/ExecutionContext;
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.<init>(JDOPersistenceManager.java:148)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.newPM(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:845)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:821)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:802)
    at test.dao.PersonDaoImp.addPerson(PersonDaoImp.java:17)
    at test.service.TestJerseyService.testMethod(TestJerseyWS.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:353)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:343)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:237)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:211)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:982)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:359)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 0):

You picked some random version of *datanucleus-core* and some other random version of *datanucleus-api-jdo* and expected them to work together, rather than using what documentation/downloads tell you to use.
https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility